# iOS and custom slider to prevent touch to parent view

Tags: ios, touch

I 've a table and a cell which holds my own slider which changes it's value when touchesMoved is called.

How do I prevent the parent cell to also receive the touch and move itself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would have to use the Pan Gesture Recognizer instead.

Comment: Does it work? I mean when you tap on the cell, it responds, but when you touch on the slider it intercepts the touch? Thanks.

Comment: You meant setting the pan gesture on the cell itself or the tableView? Thanks.